# How to separate hover effect on two chunks of code to give different properties

Tags: css, html, hover

My first post & can't find anything on here that matches what I need to know unfortunately!

I'm not an experienced coder but I've been picking it up but essentially the goal is to use the same snippet of html & CSS code for 2 sections on the website. Th difficulty is coming in when I change the opacity when on & off hover. One i want to remain at }

```
`}
.fade:hover
{
        opacity:1;
}
.fade
{
        opacity:0.8;`
```

And the other I need at

```
`}
.fade:hover
{
        opacity:1;
}
.fade
{
        opacity:0.2;`
```

The latter is taking charge and changing the opacity of the original. Is there a tag that will separate the two?

Many thanks! Any help appreciated!!

Comment: CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, the second set of rules are overriding your first set as they should. Can you add a class to the container of what you are trying to style separate. .version2 .fade, or just make a second fade class, .fade2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet, which means it reads down the file, and whatever is read last, is what will apply. So if you have 2 definitions for the same class, the latter will override the former. This is why you're only seeing the second action.

To get around this, instead of using 1 class for both buttons, use 2 classes.

```
.fade1 {
    opacity: .2;
}
.fade2 {
    opacity: .8;
}
.fade1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But even better you could simplify this down to just 3 by doing:

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<p class="fade fade1">some text</p>

/* CSS style */
.fade1 {
    opacity: .2;
}
.fade2 {
    opacity: .8;
}
.fade:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Xander! Worked a treat, I just added the fade2 class & it separated the two nicely :)

Comment: @DaleBish Great to hear! Be sure to mark an answer as 'accepted' if it worked for you so that others who come across this may see which answer worked and it also gives contributors reputation so it's a win win :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is caused by the fact the CSS cascades (CSS = Cascading Style Sheets).  What this means is that because you define the same class styles (`.fade`) twice, the instance that is defined last in the file will take precedence and overwrite the other.

What you can do to solve this is either use an additional class name or increase the css styles' specificity (meaning how specific you are in your CSS selectors).

Example 1, using an additional class:

```
.fade {
    opacity: .8;
}

.fade2 {
    opacity: .2;
}

.fade:hover, .fade2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Example 2, increasing specificity:

```
.section1 .fade {
    opacity: .8;
}

.section2 .fade {
    opacity: .2;
}

.fade:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Html would look something like this:

```
<div class="section1">
    <div class="fade">some content</div>
</div>

<div class="section2">
    <div class="fade">some other content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!! Using an additional class ( .fade / .fade2 ) worked perfectly & separated the two classes!